# Using Gson to parse JSON (Generated by Fractal)

Tags: java, android, json

I'm just wondering if someone can help me..

So, I have an API that I have developed using Fractal to parse the objects to generate some nice JSON to be consumed by an android app i'm making.

The JSON output looks a little something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Smith",
            "description": "Information about John Smith",
            "games": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "name": "Batman Arkham City",
                        "description": "Information about Game 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Silent Hill",
                        "description": "Information about Game 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

To parse this using Gson, I obviously have to create a **Person** model which has an **ArrayList** The thing is.. Note the **data** key? How do I instruct Gson to parse this? I understand removing that to have the JSON look like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Smith",
            "description": "Information about John Smith",
            "games": [
                {
                    "name": "Batman Arkham City",
                    "description": "Information about Game 1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Silent Hill",
                    "description": "Information about Game 2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My Person model looks a little something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Game> games;
```

Like I said, removing the **data** key would allow me to parse the data into Java models like so:

```
peopleArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray( "data" );
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<Person> result = new Gson().fromJson( peopleArray.toString(), listType );
```

So basically, is there any way I can tell Gson that the Games array will have a **data** key? Sorry for the information overload and hopefully that'll make sense?

Ta

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this using custom GSON serialisers/deserialisers.

http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-custom-serializer-deserializer.jsp